# Concatenate words and phrases based on conditions (Python 3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have one dataframe list like this called Single_Words:

```
Words           
The               
Man           
Was             
Funny           
and             
Handsome
```

And then another separate dataframe list like this called Bigrams:

```
Words               
The Comedian         
The Man              
Handsome Dan         
Funny Guy            
Man Down             
The Jokester         
Comedians Are
```

**What I want to do is** go through each word in the Single_Words dataframe and then concatenate it to a bigram in the second list where the FIRST word only of the bigram is the same.

So here's an example output using the word 'The' from the first dataframe and iterating through the second dataframe would yield a new list like this:

```
Words                     
The The Comedian          
The The Man               
The The Jokester
```

And using 'Man' From the first data frame and iterating through the second would give:

```
  Words   
Man Down
```

Once I have this new list and have iterated through the initial list, I plan to rinse and repeat this process by going through the original bigrams table again (up to 5 times).  So going back to the 'The' example, a second iteration would add to the list like this

```
      Words    
The The Comedian          
The The Man               
The The Jokester                    
The The Man Man Down 
The The Comedians Comedians Are
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This works, I'll try to find a better way.
Basically I use `re` to search for complete words (so that and does not match Handsome for example) and construct a dict and create a new df from that dict:

```
In [108]:

import re
temp = {'Words':[]}
def func(x):   
    for w in list(df1.Words):
        if re.search(r'\b'+x+r'\b', w):
            # just add the entry if the dict is empty
            if len(temp['Words']) == 0:
                temp['Words'] = [x + ' ' + w]
            else:
                t = temp['Words']
                t.append(x + ' ' + w)
                temp['Words'] = t

df.Words.apply(func)
total = pd.DataFrame(temp)
total
Out[108]:
                   Words
0       The The Comedian
1            The The Man
2       The The Jokester
3            Man The Man
4           Man Man Down
5        Funny Funny Guy
6  Handsome Handsome Dan
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the feedback :)  So a few things I was curious about:  1.) The 3 output is "Man The Man" -- how does this method actually search for the words?  2.) Second, I must say I'm confused where exactly I should insert my data frame variables into this code?  Does this method iterate through a list or do I manually have to put each word in?  Sorry for all the questions and thank you!

Comment: You've not specified the requirements for the match so I assumed you wanted whole word matches, the `\b` in the regular expression looks for breaks at beginning and end of the word, this stops `and` matching on `Handsome`. As the df is a different size you can either modify my code to return a Series or list so you have for each row a list of matches. Yes this manually iterates over the list in the second df which has the bigrams